# remote upload width curl/php

Tags: php, curl, upload

i have a problem, i want to upload file remote to filefactory,...
i sucessfully login and go to upload page, but when i postfields there is a error: "no file data sent". Can anyone help please... ?

my code:

```
//user data
$email="somebody@yahoo.com";
$pass="somepass";
$cookie="cookie.txt";
//url data
$host="http://www.filefactory.com";
$logURL="http://www.filefactory.com/member/login.php";
//postdata
$logPOST="email=".urlencode($email)."&password=".urlencode($pass);
//login
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $logURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $logPOST);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//go to uploads section
$uploadRefferer="http://www.filefactory.com/u/local/?login=1";
$uploadURL="http://upload.filefactory.com/upload.php";
$filename="@test.png";
//try to upload file
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uploadURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $uploadRefferer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,ALL FIELDS THAT I NEED);
curl_exec($ch);
```

File test.php is in samo folder with cookie and index.php (thats run this)... trying on localhost, server, but dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Array(
   'redirect' => 1,
   'saveTo' => 0,
   'file' => $filename
));
```